# Boilerplate: SignalR: Multiple connection call on page refresh

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspboilerplat framework of .Net core + Angular.
I am trying to integrate signalr into the same. I am able to integrate it but getting one issue while we reload the page, there are two signalr connection call one start with \signalr and second \signalr\negotiate. Second call get succeed but first call return 404 error. So can someone help to figure out this issue. What I am doing wrong here.
Please find below code that I did.

```
export class SignalRHelper {
    
    static initSignalR(callback?: () => void): void {
        
        abp.signalr = {
            autoConnect: true,
            connect: undefined,
            hubs: undefined,
            qs: 'enc_auth_token=' + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.getItem('enc-auth-token')),
            remoteServiceBaseUrl: `${environment.origin}`,
            startConnection: undefined,
            url: '/signalr',
        };
       

        const script = document.createElement('script');
        if (callback) {
            script.onload = () => {
                callback();
            };
        }
        script.src = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/abp/abp.signalr-client.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

On Page refresh, getting below error:
[image]

Comment: Your request url is too long.If you try to shorten the url,will you get 404?

Comment: Yes. it's not about URL short or long. it about why two different call?